# How to access camera and earphones in ios in PWA (React)

Tags: ios, reactjs, camera, progressive-web-apps, ios-camera

I am new to the `react js`. Here I am trying to access the mobile camera  in the app. Here,

I am trying to use the `getUserMedia` .
I am able to access the camera in the android device. But not able to access in the `IOS`.

So, I am using `react for this.`

```
if (!('getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices)) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {
                var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

                if (!getUserMedia) {
                    return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented!'));
                }

                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
                });
            }
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: { facingMode: 'user', width: 1200, height: 600 },
            audio: true
        }).then((stream) => {
            console.log('recording started');
            this.setState({
                cameraAccessGranted: true,
            });
            return this.startRecording(stream)
        }).
```

Can any one please help me with this ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: what error do you get ? Open the web inspector ( https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html ) while your device is plugged into your computer and let us know what error you get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic + Capacitor - PWA Mobile Camera Access on iOS - Works in Safari - But not when from Home Screen icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974939/ionic-capacitor-pwa-mobile-camera-access-on-ios-works-in-safari-but-not)

Comment: The frameworks are different but I believe the cause may be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it is React or not, WebRtc is not dependent on framework.
Have you tried to check examples from https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ on your android? 
For me it works well

Comment: Yes I have checked  . I will just add code which I tried